# Getting filelock [DEBUG] error scrapy that occurs when connecting to the site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm testing a really simple sports site scraper using some boilerplate code, but I'm experiencing an error where no data is scraped and the spider finishes with no data response while also receiving a debug log. The log is below.

```
2022-07-23 19:07:02 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-07-23 19:07:02 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-07-23 19:07:02 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-07-23 19:07:03 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 2064068803744 on C:\Users\Mathew Teklehaimanot\Documents\sportsData\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca216
7d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-23 19:07:03 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2064068803744 acquired on C:\Users\Mathew Teklehaimanot\Documents\sportsData\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb16
2f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-23 19:07:03 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 2064068803744 on C:\Users\Mathew Teklehaimanot\Documents\sportsData\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca216
7d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-23 19:07:03 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 2064068803744 released on C:\Users\Mathew Teklehaimanot\Documents\sportsData\lib\site-packages\tldextract\.suffix_cache/publicsuffix.org-tlds\de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb16
2f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-23 19:07:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.espn.com/nhl/scoreboard/> (referer: None)
2022-07-23 19:07:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.espn.com/soccer/scoreboard> (referer: None)
2022-07-23 19:07:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-07-23 19:07:05 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 456,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 871425,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.193903,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 2, 7, 5, 19651),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 5361597,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 7,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 2, 7, 2, 825748)}
2022-07-23 19:07:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

My code is below:

```
import scrapy


class sportsDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sportsSite"
    allowed_domains = ["www.espn.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.espn.com/soccer/scoreboard", "https://www.espn.com/nhl/scoreboard/"]

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        hockey_score_selector = response.css("div, p").extract()
```

Comment: Your parse function needs to yield an item or dictionary